# What does the code status "build: error" signify for Drush 8?

Tags: drush, installation

On the [install page for Drush 8](http://docs.drush.org/en/8.x/install/), under the section "Drupal Compatibility", the code status is listed as **"build: error"**.  What are the consequences of this, if any?